# Flutter widget parent not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image]
I am trying to create a list of reorderable items with with [Reorderables](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables) package; I have a reorderable wrap, inside it I have reorderable columns. I'm using two diffirent list for this.

```
List<Widget> items = [];

List childrenItems = [];
```

The lists are created from data looking like this

```
 List taskList = [
   // First child Item
   {
     "name":"NOrbert kRoSs",
     "sub-children":[
       "child1","child2"
     ],
   },   
   // Second child Item
   {
     "name":"Genius",
     "sub-children":[
       "Relerx","Yiuja","No filter"
     ],
   },

 ];
```

The Method used to populate the lists

```
  generateList(List incoming){
    
    List<Widget> children = [];
      children.clear();
      if(childrenItems.length > 0) {childrenItems.clear();}
      if(items != null) items.clear();

      if( incoming != null )

      for(int n=0; n<=incoming.length-1;n++){        
        
        children.clear();

        for(int sub = 0; sub<=incoming[n]["sub-children"].length-1;sub++){

          children.add(
            cardWidget(
              header: incoming[n]["sub-children"][sub]["name"].toString(),
              key: sub.toString(),
              parentKey: incoming != null?n.toString():"0",
              ),
          );
      }
                                              
        childrenItems.insert(n, children);
      
      items.add(
        mainListItem(
          nPos: n,
          header:incoming !=null?incoming[n]["name"].toString():"Aberor",
          mainKeys: n.toString(),
          ),
        );
    }
}
```

**The reorderables**

They

```
      ReorderableWrap(
        children: items != null?
          items: 
           (<Widget>[
           Container(                                
           key: ValueKey("newVal"),),
             ]), 
        onReorder: setRedorder),


              ReorderableColumn(
                children: childrenItems[nPos] != null?
                  childrenItems[nPos]: 
                  (<Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 30,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 60.0,
                    key: ValueKey("value"),
                  ),
                ]), 
              onReorder: setNewOrder,
          ),
```

**The Problem**
When I run the app I get the error below

```
Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKeys were specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The keys were:
 [GlobalObjectKey ValueKey<String>#c9f0c]
  [GlobalObjectKey ValueKey<String>#7990e]
  [GlobalObjectKey ValueKey<String>#89542]
This was determined by noticing that after widgets with the above global keys were moved out of their respective previous parents, those previous parents never updated during this frame, meaning that they either did not update at all or updated before the widgets were moved, in either case implying that they still think that they should have a child with those global keys.
The specific parents that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting are:
Column(direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: min, crossAxisAlignment: center, renderObject: RenderFlex#1c68d relayoutBoundary=up36)
```

**I am a 100% sure there are no duplicate keys and that from the error message its the parents that are not updating. How can I fix this**

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I do not understand, doing

```
children = [];
```

Instead of

```
children.clear();
```

Solves my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the different `ValueKey`.

The description in the `key.dart` said that `LocalKey(ValueKey extended LocalKey)` must be unique amongst the `Element` with the same parent.